# Issue in 2 node cluster using infinispan 5.3 | ActionStatus.ABORT_ONLY > is not in a valid state to be invoking cache operations on

Tags: infinispan, jgroups

I have a setup of 2 node cluster using Infinispan 5.3. I am testing the failover scenario. When I killed one node, i'm getting the below exception (I'm using the sync cache). The cluster is not getting. So I need to restart the application, which is not practically possible in production environment

```
         2020-05-06 18:50:28,082 ERROR [org.infinispan.interceptors.InvocationContextInterceptor] ISPN000136: Execution error
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Transaction TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: -3f57f478:dd0a:5eb2b455:2d461 status: ActionStatus.ABORT_ONLY > is not in a valid state to be invoking cache operations on.
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.TxInterceptor.enlist(TxInterceptor.java:275)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.TxInterceptor.enlistIfNeeded(TxInterceptor.java:239)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.TxInterceptor.enlistReadAndInvokeNext(TxInterceptor.java:233)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.TxInterceptor.visitGetKeyValueCommand(TxInterceptor.java:229)
        at org.infinispan.commands.read.GetKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(GetKeyValueCommand.java:62)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:120)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.handleDefault(CommandInterceptor.java:134)
        at org.infinispan.commands.AbstractVisitor.visitGetKeyValueCommand(AbstractVisitor.java:96)
        at org.infinispan.commands.read.GetKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(GetKeyValueCommand.java:62)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:120)
        at org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferInterceptor.handleTopologyAffectedCommand(StateTransferInterceptor.java:216)
        at org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferInterceptor.handleDefault(StateTransferInterceptor.java:200)
        at org.infinispan.commands.AbstractVisitor.visitGetKeyValueCommand(AbstractVisitor.java:96)
        at org.infinispan.commands.read.GetKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(GetKeyValueCommand.java:62)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:120)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.CacheMgmtInterceptor.visitGetKeyValueCommand(CacheMgmtInterceptor.java:113)
        at org.infinispan.commands.read.GetKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(GetKeyValueCommand.java:62)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:120)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.handleDefault(CommandInterceptor.java:134)
        at org.infinispan.commands.AbstractVisitor.visitGetKeyValueCommand(AbstractVisitor.java:96)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.IsMarshallableInterceptor.visitGetKeyValueCommand(IsMarshallableInterceptor.java:97)
        at org.infinispan.commands.read.GetKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(GetKeyValueCommand.java:62)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:120)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.InvocationContextInterceptor.handleAll(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:128)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.InvocationContextInterceptor.handleDefault(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:92)
        at org.infinispan.commands.AbstractVisitor.visitGetKeyValueCommand(AbstractVisitor.java:96)
        at org.infinispan.commands.read.GetKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(GetKeyValueCommand.java:62)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.InterceptorChain.invoke(InterceptorChain.java:343)
        at org.infinispan.CacheImpl.containsKey(CacheImpl.java:372)
        at org.infinispan.DecoratedCache.containsKey(DecoratedCache.java:410)
        at com.abcr.ServiceContext.existsInSyncCache(ServiceContext.java:1740)
        at com.abcr.ServiceContext.getObjectForUpdateInSyncCache(ServiceContext.java:1778)
        at com.abcr.core.cache.ClusterServiceNodeListCacheManager.getObjectForUpdate(ClusterServiceNodeListCacheManager.java:90)
        at com.suntecgroup.tbms.tpe.core.server.ServerManager.callBackOnMembersModified(ServerManager.java:3385)
        at com.abcr.core.ServiceContainerCommandDespatcher.run(ServiceContainerCommandDespatcher.java:64)
    2020-05-06 18:50:28,086 ERROR [com.abcr.core.ServiceContainer] Invocation of callback APIs on leaving coordinator role failed for service 'ABC'.
    com.suntecgroup.tbms.container.services.ContainerPlatformServicesException: Failed to retrieve object[SERVER/SERVICE_NODES/28000] for update.
```

This my infinspan and jgroups configuration

```
<infinispan
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="urn:infinispan:config:5.3 http://www.infinispan.org/schemas/infinispan-config-5.3.xsd"
      xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:5.3">
<global>
    <!-- Note that if these are left blank, defaults are used.  See the user guide for what these defaults are -->
    <asyncListenerExecutor factory="org.infinispan.executors.DefaultExecutorFactory">
      <properties>
        <property name="maxThreads" value="5" />
        <property name="threadNamePrefix" value="AsyncListenerThread" />
      </properties>
    </asyncListenerExecutor>
    <asyncTransportExecutor factory="org.infinispan.executors.DefaultExecutorFactory">
      <properties>
        <property name="maxThreads" value="25" />
        <property name="threadNamePrefix" value="AsyncSerializationThread" />
      </properties>
    </asyncTransportExecutor>
    <evictionScheduledExecutor factory="org.infinispan.executors.DefaultScheduledExecutorFactory">
      <properties>
        <property name="threadNamePrefix" value="EvictionThread" />
      </properties>
    </evictionScheduledExecutor>
    <replicationQueueScheduledExecutor factory="org.infinispan.executors.DefaultScheduledExecutorFactory">
      <properties>
        <property name="threadNamePrefix" value="ReplicationQueueThread" />
      </properties>
    </replicationQueueScheduledExecutor>
    <globalJmxStatistics enabled="false" jmxDomain="infinispan_1" />
    <!--
         If the transport is omitted, there is no way to create distributed or clustered caches.
         There is no added cost to defining a transport but not creating a cache that uses one, since the transport
         is created and initialized lazily.
         -->
    <transport clusterName="PC_SITE_1" distributedSyncTimeout="50000" transportClass="org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport">
      <properties>
        <property name="configurationFile" value="./tmp/_clusterconfig/pc_jgroups_main_sync.xml" />
      </properties>
    </transport>
    <!-- Note that the JGroups transport uses sensible defaults if no configuration property is defined. -->
    <!-- See the JGroupsTransport javadocs for more flags -->
    <!-- Again, sensible defaults are used here if this is omitted.  -->
    <serialization marshallerClass="org.infinispan.marshall.VersionAwareMarshaller" version="1.0" />
    <!--
         Used to register JVM shutdown hooks.
         hookBehavior: DEFAULT, REGISTER, DONT_REGISTER
        -->
    <shutdown hookBehavior="DEFAULT" />
  </global>
  <!-- *************************** -->
  <!-- Default "template" settings -->
  <!-- *************************** -->
  <!-- this is used as a "template" configuration for all caches in the system. -->
  <default>
    <!--
         isolation levels supported: READ_COMMITTED and REPEATABLE_READ
         -->
    <locking isolationLevel="READ_COMMITTED" lockAcquisitionTimeout="60000" writeSkewCheck="false" concurrencyLevel="5000" useLockStriping="false" />
    <!--
        Used to register a transaction manager and participate in ongoing transactions.
        -->
    <!-- ECPCacheTxManagerLookup -->
    <!--
        Used to register JMX statistics in any available MBean server
        -->
    <jmxStatistics enabled="false" />
    <!--
        Used to enable invocation batching and allow the use of Cache.startBatch()/endBatch() methods.
        -->
    <clustering mode="replication">
      <sync replTimeout="600000" />
      <stateTransfer timeout="480000" fetchInMemoryState="true" />
    </clustering>
    <storeAsBinary enabled="true" />
  </default>
  <namedCache name="GLOBAL_SYNC_CACHE">
    <transaction transactionMode="TRANSACTIONAL" transactionManagerLookupClass="com.suntecgroup.tbms.container.services.cluster.ContainerCacheTxManagerLookup" syncRollbackPhase="false" syncCommitPhase="true" useEagerLocking="true" lockingMode="PESSIMISTIC" />
  </namedCache>
  <namedCache name="GLOBAL_NONTX_SYNC_CACHE">
    <transaction transactionMode="NON_TRANSACTIONAL" />
  </namedCache>
</infinispan>
```

JGROUPS configuration..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns="urn:org:jgroups" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:org:jgroups file:schema/JGroups-2.8.xsd">
  <TCP bind_port="7800" loopback="true" recv_buf_size="20M" send_buf_size="640K" max_bundle_size="64000" max_bundle_timeout="30" enable_bundling="false" use_send_queues="true" sock_conn_timeout="300" tcp_nodelay="true" thread_pool.enabled="true" thread_pool.min_threads="1" thread_pool.max_threads="25" thread_pool.keep_alive_time="5000" thread_pool.queue_enabled="false" thread_pool.queue_max_size="100" thread_pool.rejection_policy="run" oob_thread_pool.enabled="true" oob_thread_pool.min_threads="1" oob_thread_pool.max_threads="8" oob_thread_pool.keep_alive_time="5000" oob_thread_pool.queue_enabled="false" oob_thread_pool.queue_max_size="100" oob_thread_pool.rejection_policy="run" enable_diagnostics="false" />
  <!--MPING mcast_addr="232.1.2.13"
                   mcast_port="7500"
                   num_initial_members="2"
                   timeout="2000" /-->
  <TCPPING timeout="3000" initial_hosts="${jgroups.tcpping.initial_hosts:localhost[7800],localhost[7801]}" port_range="0" num_initial_members="3" />
  <MERGE2 max_interval="100000" min_interval="20000" />
  <FD_SOCK />
  <FD timeout="60000" max_tries="5" />
  <VERIFY_SUSPECT timeout="30000" />
  <BARRIER />
  <pbcast.NAKACK use_mcast_xmit="false" exponential_backoff="500" discard_delivered_msgs="true" />
  <UNICAST timeout="300,600,1200" />
  <pbcast.STABLE stability_delay="1000" desired_avg_gossip="50000" max_bytes="400000" />
  <pbcast.GMS print_local_addr="false" join_timeout="3000" view_bundling="true" />

  FRAG2 frag_size="60000" 

  pbcast.STATE_TRANSFER
</config>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current transaction was aborted (probably due to a timeout, but maybe as a consequence of delivery failure). You need to rollback current transaction and start new.

However let me note that 5.3 was released 2013/06/26 - you're using almost 7 years old version. If there is a bug, no-one will even try to check it out.